# Vsix Private Gallery VersionRange do nothing

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Hallo i'm hosting a Private Gallery of Visual Studio Extensions.
I have 1 Extension for Visual Stduio 2019 only and
one version for Visual Studio 2022 only but when i'm looking into Visual Studio 2019 | 2022 ->Tools->Manage Extensions -> Online -> Private Gallery it shows me both version.

Wher is my mistake ?

Feedfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title>Private Gallery</title>
  <id>1111111-2222-3333-444-5555555555</id>
  <updated>2022-02-10T08:06:27Z</updated>
  <subtitle>Add this feed to Visual Studio's extension manager from Tools -&gt; Options -&gt; Environment -&gt; Extensions and Updates</subtitle>
  <link rel="alternate" href="http://test.de/Vsix/Zoom.xml" />
  <entry>
    <Id>555555-4444-3333-2222-111111111111</Id>
    <title type="text">Zoom Support for Visual Studio</title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://test.de/Vsix/Zoom\doku" />
    <link rel="releasenotes" type="text/html" href="http://test.de/Vsix/Zoom/changelog" />
    <summary type="text">Built-in support for Zooming with Microsoft Visual Studio.</summary>
    <published>2020-01-14T12:54:26Z</published>
    <updated>2022-10-11T07:14:41Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name>Test GmbH</name>
    </author>
    <content type="application/octet-stream" src="http://test.de/Vsix/Zoom/Zoom.vsix" />
    <link rel="icon" href="http://test.de/Vsix/Zoom/Zoom.ico" />
    <link href="http://test.de/Vsix/Zoom/Zoom.ico" rel="previewimage" />
    <Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-syndication-schema/2010">
      <Id>555555-4444-3333-2222-111111111111</Id>
      <Version>3.19</Version>
      <VersionRange>[16.0,17.0)</VersionRange>
      <References />
      <Installations>
        <VersionRange>[16.0,17.0)</VersionRange>
      </Installations>
    </Vsix>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>22222222-999-888-7777-55555555555</id>
    <title type="text">Zoom Support for Visual Studio</title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="http://test.de/Vsix/Zoom\doku" />
    <link rel="releasenotes" type="text/html" href="http://test.de/Vsix/Zoom/changelog" />
    <summary type="text">Built-in support for Zooming with Microsoft Visual Studio.</summary>
    <published>2020-01-14T12:54:26Z</published>
    <updated>2022-10-13T08:11:10Z</updated>
      <author>
        <name>Test GmbH</name>
      </author>
    <content type="application/octet-stream" src="http://test.de/Vsix/Zoom/Zoom_2022.vsix" />
    <link rel="icon" href="http://test.de/Vsix/Zoom/Zoom.ico" />
    <link href="http://test.de/Vsix/Zoom/Zoom.ico" rel="previewimage" />
    <Vsix xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-syndication-schema/2010">
      <Id>66666666-777-8888-9999-111111111111</Id>
      <Version>1.39</Version>
      <VersionRange>[17.0,18.0)</VersionRange>
      <ProductArchitecture>amd64</ProductArchitecture>
      <References />
      <Installations>
        <VersionRange>[17.0,18.0)</VersionRange>
      </Installations>
    </Vsix>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: You can see [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/create-a-private-gallery-for-self-hosted-visual-studio-extensions/) it provides a open source tool [Private Gallery Creator](https://github.com/madskristensen/PrivateGalleryCreator). This tool makes it easy to create ATOM feed, hope it can help you.

Comment: thanks your for the tip :) with this blog i started . But unluckly the Programm don't write any SupportRange :( so it doesn't help me

Comment: You can [create a new issue](https://github.com/madskristensen/PrivateGalleryCreator/issues). Maybe the author can provide some help

Comment: i think it's more a Feature request then a Bug report but i will create a feature request,